# marginnote vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginnote

I've run into a problem using the marginnote package; the vertical position changes if the note is wider than the margin. An MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,marginnote}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0.5in}
\begin{document}

\leavevmode%
\marginnote{Overlong}%
\lipsum[1]

\leavevmode%
\marginnote{Not Overlong}%
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The first note, wider than the margin, is set about half a line lower than the second. Using vanilla `\marginpar` instead sets both margin notes at the correct vertical position.

How can I get the vertical position to be set consistently using `\marginnote`? At this point, I'm using `\parbox`es, but then I lose the left/right justification.

Comment: If you have elements inside your `\marginnote` that is wider than `\marginparwidth`, then you can set them in boxes that shorter no wider. For example, using `\rlap{\rule{1.1\marginparwidth}{2pt}}` sets the rule in a zero-width box. I'm not exactly sure what the `\marginnote` contents is, so I don't know whether this works for you or not.

Comment: It seems that `\nolinebreak` also works: `\marginnote{\nolinebreak\rule{1.1\marginparwidth}{2pt}}`.

Comment: You'd have the same problem in a normal paragraph, if you want to start it with a rule wider than the line width. Can you make a more realistic example?

Comment: @g.kov: `\nolinebreak` didn't have any effect for me; the notes still go in different places.

Comment: @egreg: I tried starting paragraphs with long and short rules, and the vertical alignments of the two are the same; am I misunderstanding you?  Plus, like I said the question, there is no alignment problem using vanilla `\marginpar`s.

Comment: @gilgamec The difference is that `\marginnote` issues `\hspace{0pt}` before starting to typeset the text of the note, which inserts a legitimate break point; so TeX will use it and the oversized rule will go to the second line; if you try with `\unskip` before the oversized rule, it will go in the first line. With `\marginpar` the `\hspace` is not issued. Please, add a realistic example: an oversized rule *will necessarily* produce an overfull box and seems to be a little unsensical.

Comment: @egreg: Right, I understand. I'll edit the question to make it more concrete.

Comment: OK, I see now that `\marginnote` is working as intended, while my problem is that LaTeX isn't allowing the first word in the note to hyphenate; fixing that seems to get everything back into alignment.  (On that note, why does marginnote use `\hspace` rather than `\hspace*` there?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `\marginnote` issues `\hspace{0pt}` before starting to typeset the text of the note, which inserts a legitimate break point; so TeX will use it and the oversized rule will go to the second line; if you try with `\unskip` before the oversized rule, it will go in the first line. With `\marginpar` the `\hspace` is not issued.

Without a realistic example it's difficult to say more; an oversized rule will necessarily produce an overfull box and seems to be a little unsensical.